# My files disappeared from the UbuntuOne synced folder

Tags: 10.10, ubuntu-one

I set up an UbuntuOne account on PC1 (Ubuntu 10.10) and the same account on PC2 (Ubuntu 10.04).

I did the following:

1. Created file named `maverick.txt` in PC1's `~/Ubuntu One/log`
2. Created file named `venus.txt` in PC2's `~/Ubuntu One/log`

Bot files appeared in one.ubuntu.com

A few hours later, those two files are disappeared from

- PC1's `Ubuntu One/log`
- PC2's `Ubuntu One/log`
- one.ubuntu.com

So, my files are gone forever.

Why did this happen?
Is there any way to recover those files?

Comment: There probably is, but we need to find out more, and this is not the place to do it. Please [file a bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntuone-client/+filebug?field.title=My+files+are+disappeared+from+the+UbuntuOne+synced+folder) and let me know the bug number. Thanks!

Comment: Same happened to me.  Working from two pcs with Ubuntu 10.10.  Was connected to one.ubuntu from both, but now my original files are gone.  I didn't have anything in there yet worth losing sleep over, but would like to know if this is a glitch or if I did something wrong, before I save something important.

Answer (score 1):

I cant answer why Ubuntu One is failing.

**you must run foremost from live cd otherwise you will lose deleted files** (thanks for that comment!)

I recommend [DEFT Linux LiveCD](http://www.deftlinux.net/)

To recover files I recommend you foremost. Foremost is for recovering files in harddisk.

```
foremost -t doc,txt,avi,jpg -i /dev/XXXX -o tmp/recovered
```

Also you must save the recovered files in other harddisk. /dev/XXXX you should put the partition with the deleted files.

Comment: And that's really bad idea. When you install new software, you have rather good probability on overwriting deleted files from disk. Much better approach: shutdown as soon as possible and boot with live-cd.

Comment: thanks you are right, but its not a bad idea. I forget to say that :P. I usually have important data in other partition or harddisk...then installing new software will never overwrite deleted files since OS is in other partition/disk. But if he is using the same disk, that will be bad idea!